# How to use member methods as callbacks instead of static methods for a state machine like design

Tags: c++, c++11

I have some code that tends to act like a simple state machine. These are the objects I have:

```
class Actions
{
public:
    enum Action {
        action1,
        action2,
        action3
    };

    typedef void(*DoAction)(int);

    static void Start(int type) {

    }

    static void Stop(int type) {

    }

    static void NoAction(int type) {

    }
};

struct ActionCallback
{
    Actions::Action         action;
    Actions::DoAction       callback;
    ActionCallback(Actions::Action a, Actions::DoAction c) :action(a), callback(c) { }
    ActionCallback() : action(Actions::action1), callback(Actions::NoAction) { }
};
```

Here I have an `Actions` object that defines the events and callbacks and an `ActionCallback` objectthat contains an action and a callback.

Below is my `StateMachine` class - for simplicity it uses `int's` as states:

```
struct StateMachine {
    using StateMachineMap = std::map<std::pair<int, int>, ActionCallback>;
    StateMachineMap m_stateMachineMap;

    StateMachine() {
        m_stateMachineMap[std::make_pair(1, 2)] = ActionCallback(Actions::Action::action1, Actions::Start);
        m_stateMachineMap[std::make_pair(1, 3)] = ActionCallback(Actions::Action::action2, Actions::Stop);
        m_stateMachineMap[std::make_pair(1, 4)] = ActionCallback(Actions::Action::action3, Actions::Start);
        m_stateMachineMap[std::make_pair(1, 5)] = ActionCallback(Actions::Action::action3, Actions::Stop);
        m_stateMachineMap[std::make_pair(1, 6)] = ActionCallback(Actions::Action::action2, Actions::Start);
        m_stateMachineMap[std::make_pair(1, 7)] = ActionCallback(Actions::Action::action1, Actions::NoAction);
    }

    void performAction(Actions::Action action) {

    }
};
```

And this my main class that will contain the state machine and call `performAction`:

```
class Device {
    StateMachine stateMachine;
public:
    void TakeControl(int type) {

    }

    void ReleaseControl(int type) {

    }

    void NoAction(int type) {

    }
};
```

What I really want: is there a way to pass the `Device` methods as callbacks with this design instead of passing the static methods from `Actions` class ?

Something like this:

```
m_stateMachineMap[std::make_pair(1, 2)] = ActionCallback(Actions::Action::action1, Device::Start); // will trigger Device::Start to be called
```

Right now I feel it's wrong that `Device` uses `StateMachine` and `Actions` which are included in `StateMachine` will have an instance of the `Device`.

Comment: I recommend you learn about [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) and [lambda expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) (or [`std::bind`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind)).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Yeah I was thinking about std::function, but haven't really study it that much. I will, thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a difference between the type `void(*)(int)` (which you alias as `Actions::DoAction`) and the type `void(Device::*)(int)`, which is what `&Device::TakeControl` etc are.

Note that you need *both* a `Device` and an `int` to call the latter. Luckily you can adapt `ActionCallback` to use that.

```
struct ActionCallback
{
    using DeviceCall = void(Device::*)(Actions::Action);

    Actions::Action  action = Actions::action1;
    DeviceCall       callback = &Device::NoAction;
    void operator()(Device * device) { (device.*callback)(action); }
};
```

We have defined an `operator()`, so an instance of `ActionCallback` can be called like it were a function

```
struct StateMachine {
    using StateMachineMap = std::map<std::pair<int, int>, ActionCallback>;
    StateMachineMap m_stateMachineMap;

    StateMachine() {
        m_stateMachineMap[std::make_pair(1, 2)] = ActionCallback{Actions::Action::action1, &Device::Start};
        m_stateMachineMap[std::make_pair(1, 3)] = ActionCallback{Actions::Action::action2, &Device::Stop};
        m_stateMachineMap[std::make_pair(1, 4)] = ActionCallback{Actions::Action::action3, &Device::Start};
        m_stateMachineMap[std::make_pair(1, 5)] = ActionCallback{Actions::Action::action3, &Device::Stop};
        m_stateMachineMap[std::make_pair(1, 6)] = ActionCallback{Actions::Action::action2, &Device::Start};
        m_stateMachineMap[std::make_pair(1, 7)] = ActionCallback{Actions::Action::action1, &Device::NoAction};
    }

    void performAction(std::pair<int, int> what, Device * who) {
        m_stateMachineMap[what](who);
    }
};
```

There also exists a type that generalises any callable with a given signature, `std::function`.

If the `Actions::Action` were to be passed with the `Device *`, you could use

```
using ActionCallback = std::function<void(Device *, Actions::Action)>;
StateMachineMap m_stateMachineMap { { std::make_pair(1, 2), &Device::Start } };
```

However you want to associate a particular `Action` with a callback. A lambda can capture values to use when it is called.

```
using DeviceCall = void(Device::*)(Actions::Action);
using ActionCallback = std::function<void(Device *)>;
ActionCallback make_action_callback(Actions::Action action, DeviceCall callback)
{
    return [=](Device * device){ (device.*callback)(action); };
}

StateMachineMap m_stateMachineMap { { std::make_pair(1, 2), make_action_callback(Actions::action1, &Device::Start) } };
```